# What is the best way to look for the smallest element greater than 0 (or maybe in general k) in a vector?

Tags: c++, c++17

I was doing a problem and one part of it required me to find the smallest element in a vector repeatedly until they were all 0s.
The code I used to do it was this:

```
    loop
        int minE = INT_MAX;
        for(int z = 0; z < arr.size(); z++) {
            if(arr[z] > 0) {
                if(arr[z] < minE) minE = arr[z];
            }
        }
        if(minE == INT_MAX) minE = 0; // I had a case to handle them being 0, so I turn them to 0 if all elements are <= 0
        // other things (subtract minE from all positive elements and count elements with that turn to 0)
    endloop
```

Now I understand there most likely is no way to do it faster than linear time, but I was just wondering if some function in the STL could be used to achieve this kind of thing, like `min() from limits` or `lower_bound` or `min_element` or something else maybe?

edit: Just realized the problem is basically counting sort, or just is counting sort, or maybe some slight modification of it, the question is more about library functions than about the problem so don't mind this text much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a problem to be solved with the *reduce* operation, which, by the way, can also neatly be parallelized.

In general, you can couple `std::reduce` with `std::min`. In your case you need a functor/lambda that calls `std::min` after checking for zero values.

In C++20, you could also use `view::filter` to remove zero values from consideration.

Comment: I'm not very well versed in the library functions and using them at the time, (I'm just learning how to properly use binary operators and lambdas/ functors in fact), I read about reduce and let's just say, it would be very helpful if you could write an example in code for me for both filter and reduce with min!

Comment: I can't test it right now but it could look like this: `std::reduce(arr.cbegin(), arr.cend(), INT_MAX, [] (int a, int b) { if (!a) return b; if (!b) return INT_MAX; return std::min(a, b)); });` Note: Just for starters, really not thoroughly thought through.

Comment: ```std::reduce(arr.cbegin(), arr.cend(), INT_MAX, [] (int a, int b) { if (!a) return b; if (!b) return INT_MAX; return std::min(a, b); });```
Typo over there, I am also not able to try it on any online compliers at the time, guess they don't support the numeric header, will try it at home later!

Comment: `views::filter` would downgrade the `iterator_category` to at least `bidirectional_iterator_­tag` [[range.filter.iterator]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/range.filter.iterator#3).

Comment: For me using that function is not doing anything, is anyone else able to confirm whether it works?

Comment: What do you mean by "not doing anything"? You do look at what it returns, right? And it is not returning the non-zero minimum?

Comment: I was checking the array for changes instead of it's return, my bad, Accepting as answer!

Answer (score 3):

If you search the same vector repeatedly until they all are `0`, I'd recommend to filter the vector from zero values (takes O(N)), then sort the rest (takes O(NlogN), and then just `pop()` elements in the constant time from the lower end -- this would be much faster for the large arrays.

You may filter for the values less or greater than `K` on the first step, not necessarily `0`.

Comment: Yes, I did think about using an implementation with sorted array also, main purpose was learning about library functions that help with this kind of thing, also when you say pop, you mean like, reverse sort and pop the back as long as you have a zero right? (The input size was only 1000 for length of array and values, so I didn't stress too much about runtime)

Comment: @gh05t `vector` has `pop_back()` operation, you may sort the vector in the descending order or use another data structure like `list` or `deque`.

Comment: Lists will not be suitable because of linear access time (but we are more concerned with elements on edges so perhaps it will be okay too), but deque is a good choice, and filter the same as ypnos mentioned? How do you guys set up c++ 20 in windows for vs code? I think I only have support for c++ 17 I think, I use mingw gcc compiler on it.

Comment: I'm maybe super lost, but why would that approach be faster for large arrays? The proposed naive approach from the OP has a better asymptotic complexity, and better cache performance. Why would a filter + sort be faster?

Comment: @divinas do you need an explanation why O(NlogN) is faster on larger arrays than O(N**2) ?

Comment: But his solution is O(N), not O(N**2) ?

Comment: @divinas did you notice `loop` and `endloop` in the code? these mark the repeat of the inner loop until there are non-zero elements in the array, as explained above. one loop inside another gives O(N**2)

Comment: Forgive me, you are correct. This makes sense now. I missed the part where you have to do the operation repeatedly

Comment: @gh05t please, don't worry about C++20 or whatever large number you like. everything you need can be written in C++99 which is 20 years old, but still quite good and you don't need all the latest bells and whistles when you have just started to learn basics.

Comment: @lenik Yes I understand what you mean, I am learning things slowly, one thing at a time, this was just like a fun/ out of curiosity kind of thing, plus I was just learning a little bit about lambdas and binary operators, and I just got a sense this could be done in that manner so I just asked.

Comment: @lenik I think counting sort would do this in O(n), the question is basically build the count array and accumulate it, I think, not too sure, I'm at work and this randomly popped in my head, what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify the order of the elements in the vector but don't want to modify individual values, then you can use STL heap algorithms.

First partition the non-zero elements to the front and the zero elements to the back in O(n) time.
Then perform `make_heap` operation on the non-zero values which will take `O(numOfNonZeroElements)` and then repeatedly perform `pop_heap` (takes `O(log(numOfNonZeroElements))` time) on this range which will put the front element to the back of the non-zero range and then decrement the non-zero range by 1. Overall complexity is `O(n) + O(numOfNonZeroElements*log(numOfNonZeroElements))`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const vector<int>& V)
{
    for (int e : V)
        out << e << ' ';
    return out;
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    vector<int> A(n);
    for (int& e : A)
        cin >> e;

    partition(A.begin(), A.end(), [](int e) { return e > 0; });
    cout << A << endl;

    vector<int>::iterator begin, end;
    begin = A.begin();
    for (end = A.begin(); end < A.end() && *end > 0; end = next(end));
    make_heap(begin, end, greater<int>());
    while (begin < end && A.front() > 0)
    {
        cout << A.front() << endl; // perform operation on A.front() here
        pop_heap(begin, end, greater<int>());
        cout << A << endl;
        end = prev(end);
    }
}
```

Comment: I like your idea, I've not practiced heaps enough that I can tell you if it can be used but the thing I have to do in that question is basically, know how many total positive element the array has in each iteration and remove all the minimum valued in each iteration, go to the next iteration and repeat. So I suppose you will need loop in loop but this way it will run much more optimally, kind of like doing it on a sorted array and poping, but using the heap structure. I will try to implement this for practicing heaps thanks!